# Convert Stream to IEnumerable. If possible when "keeping laziness"

Tags: c#

I recieve a Stream and need to pass in a IEnumerable to another method.

```
public static void streamPairSwitchCipher(Stream someStream)
{
    ...
    someStreamAsIEnumerable = ...
    IEnumerable returned = anotherMethodWhichWantsAnIEnumerable(someStreamAsIEnumerable);
    ...
}
```

One way is to read the entire Stream, convert it to an Array of bytes and pass it in, as Array implements IEnumerable. But it would be much nicer if I could pass in it in such a way that I don't have to read the entire Stream before passing it in.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> anotherMethodWhichWantsAnIEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> p) {
    ... // Something uninteresting
}
```

Comment: What is it expecting to enumerate? Is it *really* wanting to enumerate each byte of the stream?

Comment: You can create a wrapper, wrapping the stream, providing the IEnumerable support, implemented just the way you want it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I plan on enumerating the bytes of a file and let `anotherMethodWhichWantsAnIEnumerable` which is already implemented do its magic on it.

Comment: @Binary255: Odd... most things which need a sequence of bytes would just use a stream...

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as accepted answer, or provide more information, if your not happy with any our answers.

Comment: Of course I was going to. I just haven't been around. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This one reads your stream byte by byte 'on demand':

```
public static IEnumerable<byte> streamAsIEnumerable(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");

    for (; ; )
    {
        int readbyte = stream.ReadByte();
        if (readbyte == -1)
            yield break;
        yield return (byte)readbyte;
    }
}
```

Or even shorter, and not raising an exception if the stream is null, but just yielding nothing:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte> streamAsIEnumerable(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream != null)
        for (int i = stream.ReadByte(); i != -1; i = stream.ReadByte())
            yield return (byte)i;
}
```

Comment: Just tested it and noticed the same :) Corrected it.

Comment: I assumed you want an IEnumerable<byte>. If you wanted something else (e.g. IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<string> containing all Lines of a TextStream, ...) let me know.

Answer (score 6):

I did some experiments on this and wrote something similar to phild:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<byte> Bytes(this Stream stm)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int c = stm.ReadByte();
            if (c < 0)
                yield break;
            yield return (byte)c;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<char> Chars(this TextReader reader)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int c = reader.Read();
            if (c < 0)
                yield break;
            yield return (char)c;
        }
    }
}
```

The difference here is that I have added Bytes and Chars to Stream as an extension method which lets me write something like this:

```
foreach (char c in Console.In.Chars()) { /* ... */ }
```

And for grins, I wrote an abstract class called TokenizingStateMachine that uses IEnumerable on TextReader to implement IEnumerable so that a simple parser can do something like:

```
foreach (Token t in stateMachine) {
}
```